# Access the apps ngrx store from new Object

Tags: angular, ngrx

I understand that the current ngrx store can be accessed by injecting it into things like angular 2 components but I need to dispatch an event from a separate object. Many copies of the object can be created on the fly by the application.

For example assuming you have app set up per the ngrx:store readme example and I need to access the store and trigger it from something like this.

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

export class RandomObj {
 name: string;
 number: number;

 constructor(name, number) {
  this.name = name;
  this.number = number;
 }

 amazingEvent(){
  // How to do this sort of thing so the app store will respond?
  this.store.dispatch({type: 'AMAZING_ACTION', payload: this});
 }
}
```

Edit:

What will work, somewhat obviously, is passing the store into RandomObj when you initialise it.

Answer (score -1):

1. read this: [link](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html#dependency-injection-as-a-pattern)
2. u need to use the RelfectiveInjector like:

   var injector = RelfectiveInjector.
         { provide: Store, useClass: Store}
       ]);

and in the constructor use:
@Inject(Store) store

- after that u can use the store anywhere in your class and call to dispatch

Comment: Doesn't seem to be it gives: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Store'(?, ?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Store' is decorated with Injectable. So guessing you need to know the dependencies for store, also slightly worried that will create a new store not give access to the main apps store.

Comment: Didn't down vote you. Maybe stackoverflow has down vote trolls on it now.